# Failed to save undefined: The attribute "Option" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://ui:inputText: Source

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
     <div class="slds-form-element__control">
         <ui:inputText aura:id="groupType"
                 label="group Type"
                 class="slds-select"
                 Option="Standard"
                 labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                 value="{!v.groupType.Name}"
                 required="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here I should be able select one option from the list of avaialble options, the options are standard, medium, complex**

Comment: option is not an attribute supported by ui:inputtext, where did you get that from http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?descriptor=ui:inputText&defType=component

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `ui:inputText` and `ui:inputSelect` (from the answer provided) are both deprecated and unsupported. Use `lightning:select` or `lightning:combobox` instead. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:inputSelect/example

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<ui:inputSelect>`, attribute `options` present

below is the documentation for `<ui:inputSelect>`

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
        <ui:inputSelect label="Status" class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic"/>
</aura:component>
```

---

JS

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp) {
        var opts = [{ class: "optionClass", label: "Open", value: "Open"},
                               { class: "optionClass", label: "Completed", value: "Completed" },
                                { class: "optionClass", label: "Open&Completed", value: "Open&Completed" },
                              ];  
        cmp.find("InputSelectDynamic").set("v.options", opts);
    }
})
```

http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?descriptor=ui:inputSelect&defType=component